# aws: Application traffic passing through NAT gateways?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nat, kops

I am deploying a microservices app using `kubernetes` on `aws`.

One of the pods will be the ui and will be exposed as a `LoadBalancer` service.

This creates an ELB that has the `k8s` nodes as instances behind it.

The `k8s` cluster is deployed using the `--topology private` flag of `kops`, so all nodes are in private subnet and some NAT gateways are created for allowing these private instances to receive traffic.

The app architecture as I said will expose ports 80/443 (accessible via the ELB) and once hit, will perform several back-end tasks before returning a result.

The question is the following: given that NAT instances are also charged per GB processed, will this application-based traffic increase my costs?

Or is the application traffic tunneled **only** via the ELB?

Answer (score 2):

The load balancer should be in the public subnets, and back end in the private subnets should be accepting traffic from the load balancer.

In this scenario, only traffic initiated by the back end would traverse the NAT.  If the containers are immutable, you probably do not need the NAT gateways.

Comment: Aren't they needed for the instances to receive updates?

Comment: If you're updating in place, then yes.  Amazon Linux should be able to pull updates from S3 via a VPC Endpoint though.

Comment: In theory, IPVS with DSR might be able to reply directly from the instances.  But this seems quite experimental at the moment https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kube-aws/issues/1073